# How to change text to normal font inside \itshape?

Tags: italic, text-decorations

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{italic}{\begin{quote}\itshape}{\end{quote}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rad}{rad}

\begin{document}

\begin{italic}
blablabla
    \begin{displaymath}
    \rad(R)=\{x\in R\mid x^n=0 \text{ where we consider } n\geq 1\}
    \end{displaymath}
more blablabla

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $x^n$ with $n=1$
        \item $y^m$ with $m=2$
    \end{enumerate}

\end{italic}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the *blablabla* to be italic, but the text in the mathematical environment (for example "where we consider" and "with") shouldn't be. In my document, I have quite a lot of these *blablabla*'s between mathematical environments, so that's the reason why I use the self-defined *italic* environment: to save some time and don't have to use `\textit` or `\itshape` all the time.

How can I solve this? Is this a good approach?

---

**Edit:** I've updated my question and changed the title, because the code I gave in the beginning didn't really reflect my situation. My mistake... I've used the tip to declare *rad* as a mathematical operator.

Comment: Isn't `amsmath` needed to use `\text`?

Comment: @Jeroen Are you trying to write the statement of a theorem?

Comment: @egreg: Well, it's the formulation of an exercise, so it's not really a theorem.

Comment: According to the standard typesetting rules, the words ”where we consider” should use the current font, italic in this case. Not “rad”, which is a math symbol and must be upright.

Comment: @egreg: Really? That would solve my problem immediately! Where can I actually read these typesetting rules? Everyone talks about them, but I don't know where to find them... (sounds stupid)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `\textit` macro does not generally control the appearance of the text in the math environment.  That's done separately.

In math mode you can use

```
\mathrm{rad}
```

Or if this is to be the name of a function you can load the `amsmath` package in the  preamble

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

and then in the body of the text call

```
\operatorname{rad}
```

If this is something you will want to call repeatedly you can define a command to accomplish this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rad}{rad}
```

and then in the body of the document you can write

```
\[
  \rad(R)=\{x\in R\mid x^n=0 \text{ with }n\geq 1\}
\]
```

If additionally you wish the `with` not to be set in italics, you can do something like

```
\text{\normalfont\ with }
```

or

```
\textnormal{ with }
```

You need to make this change within `\text{...}` because it inherits the style of the fonts outside of the math environment.

[image]

You should notice that `\normalfont` is a switch command like `\bfseries` which remains in effect until the end of the current group.
As `\textbf{...}` corresponds to `{\bfseries ....}`, `\textnormal{...}` corresponds to `{\normalfont ...}`.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question: It does not work because you are in math-mode. On the other hand, if you are not in math-mode, something like

```
\textit{Blablabla \normalfont{Normalfont Bla} More Bla}
```

won't work too because normalfont does not take an argument. Try this one to see the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textit{Blablabla {\normalfont Normalfont Bla} More Bla}
\end{document}
```

Moreover you don't need to use math in `\textit`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\textit{blablabla}
\begin{displaymath}
  \mathrm{rad}(R)=\{x\in R\mid x^n=0 \text{ with } n\geq 1\}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Regarding your edit:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\AMStext\text
\newenvironment{italic}
  {\renewcommand{\text}[1]{\AMStext{\normalfont ##1}}
  \begin{quote}\itshape}
  {\end{quote}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rad}{rad}

\begin{document}
\begin{italic}
blablabla
  \begin{displaymath}
    \rad(R)=\{x\in R\mid x^n=0 \text{ where we consider } n\geq 1\}
  \end{displaymath}
more blablabla
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $x^n \text{ with } n=1$
    \item $y^m \text{ with } m=2$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{italic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One can use `\textnormal`

Comment: ... which takes one argument and would work in the way as `\normalfont` was used in the OP (just for completeness :-)

Answer (score 2):

What A. Ellet said can be simulated  in a complete code snippet as follows. `thm` environment makes the enclosed text italic. As `\text` inherits the font from the outside environment, the text `\text{ with }` becomes italic as well. To change it back to normal font, use either `\text{ \normalfont with }` or `\text{ \textnormal{with} }`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\rad}{rad}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[\textbackslash textnormal]
\[
  \rad(R)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x^n=0 \text{ \textnormal{with} } n\geq 1\}
\]
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}[\textbackslash normalfont]
\[
  \rad(R)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x^n=0 \text{ \normalfont with } n\geq 1\}
\]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

You can also change the symbol `R` by `\mathbb{R}` to make it clearer as a real number set. Does it seem to be more fancy?

[image]

Note: It is a community wiki answer, just to prevent me from getting reputation points whenever the readers vote it up.

Comment: Actually, the *R* marks a ring, not the real number set. :)