# Ampersand, &, inside a theorem?

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, ampersand

When I try to write the symbol "&" inside a theorem it looks different than I want it to. Is there a way to get the symbol inside the theorem? Here is what I get:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    Outside theorem \&
\begin{theo}
    Inside theorem \&

    Inside theorem 2 \text{\&}
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Do you see how to fix this?

Comment: Theorems are italic by default. You could use `{\normalfont \&}` in these cases as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147779/).

Comment: You can also try `\textup{\&}` and `\textsl{\&}`

Comment: Can you show a “real world” example of usage, please?

Comment: @egreg Inside a proof referring to and article written by two mathematicians. The article uses "&" instead of "and" between the names.

Comment: Use “and” instead, they're not a business company. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

The suggestions in the comments work, but it sounds to me like you still want a properly italic ampersand, just not in that design. There are two solutions to this:

1. Use a different font altogether.  Tgtermes is close to computer modern (the default tex font), but gives you the ampersands that you want.

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amsthm}
   \usepackage{tgtermes}
   \newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

   \begin{document}
       Outside theorem \&
   \begin{theo}
       Inside theorem \&

   Inside theorem 2 \&
   \end{theo}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Borrow an individual character from another font.  See e.g. [Font substitution with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23049/font-substitution-with-xelatex)

[image]

Comment: Inside a list you need to indent code blocks by eight instead of four spaces

Comment: Package tgtermes gives you the font Computer Modern in math mode, but the font Times in text mode, hence the different (Times) ampersand.